# Creating a function that returns the argument in the least amount of numbers from a list

Tags: python, function, loops

I'm new to Python programming and I'm trying to create a function on which I specify a number(argument), and then, from a list I created, I get that number(argument) represented in the least numbers possible.

So far I've written this code, but I seem to be getting something wrong(I'll explain the logic I'm making in the code comments):

```
def count_money(monto):
    bill = 1000, 500, 200, 100, 50, 25, 20, 10, 5, 1 
    for x in bill:
        total = (monto/x)
        if total >= 1: # if this division is bigger than one, it means there's one bill which can be taken.
            print(x) % Here I take the bill
            monto = (monto%x) # we update the argument to be the residual of the division so that the loop continues with this new argument. However, when the division equals exactly one, which would be the last number, then it will also print this number.
```

If I print, for example, count_money(150), then I get one bill of a 100 and a bill of 50. But if I play around with other numbers it's wrong.

Please don't tell me the answer, just point me towards the right direction on what I'm doing wrong with my code.

Thanks.

Comment: Include an example of a number that you can use that makes it wrong.

Comment: For example: 
count_money(7000)
count_money(400)

Comment: I gave it a go with the number 27 and I think I see the source if the problem. Consider this - you are iterating over every number in `bill`, meaning every bill size can be used only once... Do you see what I'm getting at?

Comment: Hmm, honestly, no. I thought that once I updated the argument, then the argument will iterate through the bills once again. Do you mean use the bill twice in the iteration?

Edit: I get what you mean. For instance, for 27 it only prints until 26 because it can't use the 1 bill twice. Although I don't think I've learned how to use the numbers twice.

Comment: You are losing information when you are setting monto to the modulus of x

Comment: rather than trying to check a bill again, you might check to see how many of a bill you can use.

Comment: Quite right. Iterating twice won't solve your problem, because a number like 28, for example, will require 3 iterations. You have to figure out a more generic solution, like trying the same bill continuously until it doesn't fit anymore, or (my personal preference) when you calculate `total`, round it down to the nearest whole number - this will give you the number of times the bill fits inside `monto`.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, the problem is that in the current version of the code every bill can only be used once, because you are iterating over the list, checking one bill at a time and moving on.

This fix should solve the problem:

```
import math

def count_money(monto):
    bill = 1000, 500, 200, 100, 50, 25, 20, 10, 5, 1 
    for x in bill:
        total = math.trunc(monto/x) # Total is now the rounded down number of times the bill being checked fits inside monto (or what's left of it)
        if total < 1:
            continue # This means the bill doesn't fit at all
        for i in range(total):
            print(x) # print the bill the number of times it fits
        monto = (monto%(total * x)) # Remove the full amount we already accounted for (which is the bill x the number of times we used it)
```

I kept the original variable names, but they should be altered for readability purposes, since their use has now changed.